# jquery clear input fields if the checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery, what is letting the user to fill out additional fields in the form if the check box is checked. What I want is to clear the additional inputs fields values if the check box is unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    $('#xml').hide();
    $('#checkbox').click(function() {
        $('#xml')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
    });
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('div#xml p label input').attr('required', true);
        }

        else

            $('div#xml p label input').removeAttr('required', true);

        //Here should the corresponding code to be pasted 
                   //$('div#xml p label input').val = ('');

    });

$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 $('div#xml p label input').val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('div#xml p label input').attr('required', true);
    }else{
        $('div#xml p label input').removeAttr('required', true);
        $('div#xml p label input').val('');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pizzaOption>input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var pizzaPrice=$(this).closest("#pizzaOption").data('price');
     console.log(price);
       $('#total').html(pizzaPrice);
    } else {
      var pizzaPrice=0;
      $('#total').html(pizzaPrice);
    }
    });
});
  </script>
```