# get data-attr from a form input checkbox using JS

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

If someone puts a checkmark, I want to get the data-price attribute. Nothing is appearing in the console.log. I tried using .prop('checked'), .data('checked'), and .attr('checked'). I am assuming something is wrong with the Syntax?

This article[Get data-price jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387461/get-data-price-jquery) code as below does not seem to work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      if $('#pizzaOption').click(function() {
    var price=$(this).data('price');
     console.log(price);
    });

 <form action="" id="pizzaOption" data-price="5">Large Pizza <br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="sausage">Sausage<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Used this article to no success. https://medium.com/js-dojo/check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery-2843f97d4954 Code is below:

```
  <script type= text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked') {
    var price=$(this).data('price');
     console.log(price);
    }
                     }    
    </script>
```

Comment: probably syntax error in document.ready

it should be 

$(document).ready(function(){
// ...
})

Comment: yes i am getting a [ ]  in console now... looks like a blank array. interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of mistake in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ {
      if $('#pizzaOption').click(function() {
    var price=$(this).data('price');
     console.log(price);
    });
```

You have `{ {` in callback function of `$(document).ready()` and it is not closed with `});` And you have if in your click event which results syntax error.

In your second code

```
<script type= text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked') {
    var price=$(this).data('price');
     console.log(price);
    }
                     }    
    </script>
```

You have checked the `attr('checked')` but there is no event binded on it and will always result false because no checkbox is checked onload event and `$(this).data('price');` is undefined because `data-price` on the parent element of the clicked checkbox.

And you have click event on `'#pizzaOption'` according to your question you need to bind the click event on `checkbox` here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pizzaOption>input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var price=$(this).closest("#pizzaOption").data('price');
     console.log(price);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="" id="pizzaOption" data-price="5">Large Pizza <br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="sausage">Sausage<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Another example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pizzaOption>input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var price=$(this).closest("#pizzaOption").data('price');
     console.log(price);
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="pizzaOption" data-price="5">Large Pizza <br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="sausage">Sausage<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
      <input type="checkbox"  value="mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: ok thanks your code worked marked as solution. on second thought, i will need to update it so it only triggers the price if checked but i will do some research on that

Comment: @chessmaster1 I have updated my answer check second snippet

Comment: Cool, your additional solution totally worked. https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/QzGWGP?editors=0001  If you have time, I made a codepen. When i added `$('#total').html(price);` after console.log(price)... the 5 does not go away after "an unclick". This is very unexpected, not sure how to 'google' this one...

Comment: nevermind, figured it out using this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939247/jquery-clear-input-fields-if-the-checkbox-is-unchecked    added `else {
      var price=0;
      $('#total').html(price);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" id="pizzaOptions" data-price="5">Large Pizza <br>
   <input type="checkbox"  value="sausage">Sausage<br>
   <input type="checkbox"  value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
   <input type="checkbox"  value="mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
// wait until document is ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    // For every checkbox checked inside form
    $('#pizzaOptions input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
       // display value
       console.log($(this).val())

       // now if you want to get the price you should 
       console.log($('#pizzaOptions').attr('data-price'))
    })
 })
```